# Sort items in the list based on the occurance of the item in a string

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I am a newbie to python

I have a string and list like this

```
s='''Hello, Carry out the item with care
Louis, MS to Dallas, TX '''
```

```
LOC=['Dallas','Louis']
```

How to sort the list according to the occurrence of the word from a string?

Desired Output:

```
LOC =['Louis','Dallas']
```

Considering the word in the list doesn't repeat multiple times in the string.

Comment: based on the index of the occurrence?

Comment: LOC has 2 items DALLAS and LOUIS but the item 'LOUIS' occurs 1st in the string so it should be the 1st element of the list and DALLAS should be the 2nd element of the list@Marcos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the method `index` of strings to find the position of the occurrence, then do a `sort` of that list based on that, for example:

```
s = '''Hello, Carry out the item with care
Louis, MS to Dallas, TX '''

LOC = ['Dallas', 'Louis', 'TX', 'out']

sorted_LOC = sorted(LOC, key=s.index)

print(sorted_LOC)
>>> ['out', 'Louis', 'Dallas', 'TX']
```

Comment: Thank you @Marcos it worked well for my sample.

Comment: @Manuel u r right! getting too used to javascript. Updating it.